# Regarding @Html.DropDownListFor(...)

Tags: asp.net, razor, dropdownlistfor

Can someone please help me figure this out. I have a Drop Down List in ASP.NET Razor code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Height, heightlist, new { style = "font-size:120%;" })
```

My Drop Down List is too big when you click on the list. I would like it to be like the one on the right hand side:

[image]

I tried various methods, including the code below, but the issue exists:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Height, heightlist, new { height="50", style = "font-size:120%; height:30px;" })
```

Comment: uhm, remove the `font-size: 120%;` style rule.

Comment: Also, the rendering of the `<select>` element is controlled by the browser, there are very limited styling options (e.g. on iOS Safari it's rendered as a spinner at the bottom of the browser, not as a popup drop-down menu).

Comment: The screenshot of the other height-list is not a `<select>` element, it's a bit of custom JavaScript and HTML that *mimics* a `<select>`.

Comment: @Dai:  I tried the change you mentioned and removed the font-size:120%;  but it only made the list box smaller. The height is still there. I think I will have to change the height using Javascript maybe ?